# How to read a file which in CSV format, but different extension?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataset which has a good dataframe structure starting from row 3. For the first rows, unfortunately separators are diverse, and there is a few information to be included in my dataframe. The files are in CSV strcture mostly, but they have extensions like WOC, WOL, WPL, and so on.

The WOC file first rows look like:

```
Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?

144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld






45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

Header of the ollowing values should be like:

```
A, B, C, D, E
45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0
```

Here is my attempt:

```
df44 = pd.DataFrame() # creates empty dataframe

for f in glob.glob('file_path_to_single_file'):

    with open(f, 'rb') as file:
        encodings = chardet.detect(file.read())["encoding"]
    a = pd.read_csv(f,sep='\s+|;|,', engine='python', encoding=encodings,header=None,names=['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], skiprows=2)
    df44 = df44.append(a)
```

What would be the best way to read such a file so that I can also extract height, weight, age and city?

My expected output is:

```
A, B, C, D, E, City, Height, Weight, Age
45,34,22,26,0,NewYork, 144,    35,   5
78,74,82,11,0,NewYork, 144,    35,   5
```

Comment: The extension does not matter. "*The files are in CSV strcture mostly*" -> looks like you need to skip the initial lines

Comment: @mozway If I skip the lines, how am I supposed to obtain  height, weight, age and city info?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=2, names=['age', 'height', 'weight', "city"])`?

Comment: CSV means Comma Separated Values. It's a text file with values separated by commas. The extension doesn't matter. That's what `read_csv` or Python's `csv` module can read. The header rows are something completely different. You can read the CSV values with `read_csv` but to read the headers you'll have to actually read those lines and parse them.

Comment: Even if `read_csv` could read the header, where would those values go? Would you add them as columns that repeat the same value in every row?

Comment: @mozway height, weight, age and city info are in the 2nd row. If I skip first two rows, I cannot see them. The comma separated numerical values should have the following columns: [A, B, C, D, E]

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah I would add them as columns that repeat the same value in every row

Comment: You can't do that with `read_csv`. These aren't comma separated values. You could read the first few lines and eg use regular expressions or splitting to extract the parts you want. If you only care about the third line's data, you could split by `/`. Or you could use a regex that captures height, weight and age directly. To read the numeric data though you'll have to use read_csv with `skiprows=9` and provide the column names

Comment: Where would `city` come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos then am I supposed to somehow combine output of regex and read_csv? If so, how would that be?

Comment: @dspractician Does those different file extensions WOC, WOL, WPL, and so on have only one separator option? E.g. WOC always has ; WOL always has | and others have their ones.

Comment: @1001001 No, they have mixed separators.

Comment: So there is no consistency at all in those files? In your example in first, perhaps Heading rows there are some information and then below structured data. Could you provide expexted output? Which data from first rows you need to parse?

Comment: @1001001 I just added the expected output. I need to parse, age, height, and weight info

Comment: One more thing. In first two rows are the city name always in this format after bunch of other characters `? Z:C`. Also, does Height, Weight, Age always in this format with only those numbers with its own dimensions names divided by backslash?

Comment: @1001001 Exactly formatting is always same. However, there are sometimes weights of float value like 54,4 instead of integer. We can make a solution for integer weights initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on additional info from your comments above I think you can start build your solution with following:

```
`# I created a file 'data.woc' with data as stream from your question:`
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re
stack_data = '''Person:?,?;F dob. ?  MT: ? Z:C NewYork Mon.:S St.?

144 cm/35 Kg/5 YearsOld






45,34,22,26,0
78,74,82,11,0'''

# read heading rows, I arbitrally chose 5 rows to read

with open('data.woc', 'r') as f:
    heading_rows = [next(f) for _ in range(5)]

city = re.findall(pattern = ' \w+ ', string = heading_rows[0])[0].strip()

numbers_list = [re.findall(pattern='\d+', string=row) for row in heading_rows if 'cm' and 'kg' in row.lower()][0]

height, weight, age = [int(numbers_lst[i]) for i in range(3)]
    
df = pd.read_csv('data.woc', sep='\s+|;|,', skiprows=2,comment='cm', index_col=None, names=list('ABCDE'))
    
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I just noticed for some files the empty area is longer, so skipping row value should be bigger. Do you think I should delete those extra lines? Or how can I find a solution for those extra lines? there is ---- between some line

Comment: @dspractician If you're sure that those extra characters like `------` are only in rows you don't need you can add this `-` character to 'comment' argument in `pd.read_csv` and then `df.dropna` will do the job.  Are those empty parts in each file only between headings and data? Or maybe also between your data rows.

Comment: Comment works, but there are various extra characters in between. Ishould make a new queston about it I guess